# Is the database class in Laravel use the "Singleton Pattern"?

Tags: laravel, database-design

I am new to Laravel. Does the Laravel create a database connection every time for each query of the program or use the same database object throughout the program using the "Singleton" Pattern?  Does the strategy have an impact on performance, especially for Enterprise Level Applications?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Short answer

No, it's not a singleton, but a factory pattern. However the same connection will be reused if possible and you don't manually request it to reconnect. There is no performance hit.

## Long answer

At the beginning of ever request lifecycle, in `app/bootstrap/start.php` an instance of `Illuminate\Foundation\Application` gets created. This servers as IoC container.

Shortly after creating the application all [service providers](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/ioc#service-providers) will be loaded. The service providers are defined in `app/config/app.php`

```
'providers' => array(
    // ...
    'Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider',
    // ...
),
```

Let's have a look at the `Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider` shall we? The important part is the `register` function

```
$this->app->bindShared('db', function($app)
{
    return new DatabaseManager($app, $app['db.factory']);
});
```

An instance of `DatabaseManager` gets bound to `db`. This instance will stay the same over the whole request and will be used for every database request.

### Example from "reverse" direction

Say you call

```
DB::table('users')->get();
```

First, the `DB` [facade](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/facades) will resolve to the instance of `DatabaseManager` that gets bound in the `DatabaseServiceProvider` using `bindShared('db')`

```
protected static function getFacadeAccessor() { return 'db'; }
```

Then the `table('users')` call gets forwarded because the method doesn't exist in `Database Manager`

```
public function __call($method, $parameters)
{
    return call_user_func_array(array($this->connection(), $method), $parameters);
}
```

It is called on the return value of `$this->connection()`

```
public function connection($name = null)
{
    list($name, $type) = $this->parseConnectionName($name);

    // If we haven't created this connection, we'll create it based on the config
    // provided in the application. Once we've created the connections we will
    // set the "fetch mode" for PDO which determines the query return types.
    if ( ! isset($this->connections[$name]))
    {
        $connection = $this->makeConnection($name);

        $this->setPdoForType($connection, $type);

        $this->connections[$name] = $this->prepare($connection);
    }

    return $this->connections[$name];
}
```

With `if (!isset($this->connections[$name]))` it will check if the connection already has been established and will only make a new connection if not.

Then it returns the connection and `table('users')->get()` will be executed.

Comment: to be precise, say: **Short version - no, it's not singleton, but factory pattern. However the same connection will be used by default and if it's already available and if not requested otherwise by the dev, so there's no performance hit**.

Comment: Thanks mate. I incorporated your suggestion into the answer.

Comment: Thanks it really helps me to go with Laravel.

Comment: @MohitVerma Glad I could help. Please consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) this answer to mark your question as solved.